# How do I pass the guild variable to an event file in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using the guide in [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#event-handling) to have separate event listener files, and was trying to add another one. Specifically, the guildCreate event. In the index.js file, I have this:

```js
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (message, guild, ...args) => event.execute(message, guild, ...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (message, guild, ...args) => event.execute(message, guild, ...args));
    }
}
```

And on the event side, I have this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = require('../config.json')

module.exports = {
    name: 'guildCreate',
    once: true,
    async execute(client, guild) {
        console.log(guild)
        const introembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Hiya!')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(`Long description here`)
        const owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
        owner.send({ embeds: [introembed]}).catch(console.error())
        console.info(`I just joined a new server! I am now a member of ${guild.name}`)
    },
};
```

When the guildCreate event is emitted, I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchOwner')` because of `await guild.fetchOwner();`. I have tried passing the variable from the index side: `client.on(event.name, (message, guild, ...args) => event.execute(message, guild, ...args));`, as you can see, I added the guild variable to be passed, and on the event file side: `async execute(client, guild) {` I added the guild variable to be executed with.
Even with adding the variables in those places, I still get the error saying guild is undefined. Any idea what is wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you passing in `message` and `guild` into the events if A) you haven't defined them and B) Not all events emit a message and guild object. Simply pass in `...args` and the callback arguments for their respective events will match up

Comment: Guild should be defined when it is emitted, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This is optimized for Discord.js v13.3.0*

---

### Passing in Empty Variables

As pointed out by [@Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931), passing in `message` and `guild` have no value as they are never defined in your code anywhere. This can lead to Errors being thrown due to undefined variables (Unless you have error handlers in your code elsewhere). As stated in the guide, the `...args` argument will pass in any arguments received from the event. This is how something like that would work:

- An event is received (Let's use `guildCreate`)
- The process searches your files

```
discord-bot/
├── node_modules
├── config.json
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── events
    └ guildCreate.js
```

- Once it finds a match, it executes the code.
  In the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate), it is noted that only a guild is sent when  the event is fired. This means that `...args` will only contain one argument, which is a Guild. **Arguments from events do not have names, the ones in the documentation are recommended.**

The issue with your code is that you have sent an empty variable called `guild` to the execution file.

```js
async execute(client, guild) {
```

The code looks at this line and uses the empty variable you sent called `guild`. This is why you're receiving a TypeError.

### Single Argument Events

To fix this, all you need to do is remove the two arguments `client` and `guild` from your `index.js` file and remove the `client` from your `guildCreate.js` file. The result will look something like this:

```
// index.js
if (event.once) {
 client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
} else {
 client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
}

// guildCreate.js
async execute(guild) {
```

### Multiple Argument Events

Sometimes, you'll receive events that have multiple arguments, such as [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd). That event will give you two (Unnamed) arguments **in this order**: a [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/MessageReaction) and a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/User). This is how that'd look:

```js
// index.js
if (event.once) {
 client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
} else {
 client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
}

// messageReactionAdd.js
async execute(messageReaction, user) {
```

Take note that I haven't defined any arguments in index.js and only defined them in `messageReactionAdd.js`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I did not know everything was passed through `..args`. I probably could have avoided this just by reading the guide more carefully.